# Header response "403 Forbidden" with cURL, file_get_contents() and fopen()

Tags: php

I'm hoping you'll be able to help me.
The site is currently online and I can access it fine, I can't seem to understand why this isn't working.

`file_get_contents()` and `fopen()` return an error saying the following:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.hackforums.net): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /host/Users/Phizo/Desktop/stalker.php on line 29
```

Now I just started taking up cURL since I wanted to try get around this 403, also no luck.

```php
$handle = curl_init();
$file = fopen('source.txt', 'w');

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.hackforums.net/');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);

curl_exec($handle);

print_r(curl_getinfo($handle));

curl_close($handle);
fclose($file);
```

Outputs the following error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\Hosting\6514439\html\zeonsglobal\admin\press_uploads\stalker.php on line 29
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works for me, you don't need to perform a custom request to achieve what you want.

```
$handle = curl_init();

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.hackforums.net/');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($handle);

var_dump($result);

curl_close($handle);
```

The likely reason you were getting a 403 was because of the user agent that fopen was passing.  If you remove the user agent from the curl request you will also get a 403 error.

I added the curl option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` so it returns the response in a string when you call `curl_exec()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me, however I managed to solve the issue using stream_context_create(). It seems that fopen was passing the user agent "PHP" just like you said. So you helped me come up with a way to do it, thanks :).